# Compiling Z3 test examples gives build error

Tags: z3

I've compiled Z3 from sources at codeplex. Configuration details:

- Operation system Debian 5.0 (Lenny)
- GLIBC 2.7
- GCC 4.4.3
- OpenMP 4.3.4 (package version)

When I try to build the c example I get:

```
../../lib/libz3.so: undefined reference to `std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const@GLIBCXX_3.4.11'
```

When I try to build the c++ example I get:

```
../../lib/libz3.so: undefined reference to `omp_init_nest_lock@OMP_3.0'
../../lib/libz3.so: undefined reference to `omp_unset_nest_lock@OMP_3.0'
../../lib/libz3.so: undefined reference to `omp_set_nest_lock@OMP_3.0'
../../lib/libz3.so: undefined reference to `omp_destroy_nest_lock@OMP_3.0'.
```

The examples mentioned were downloaded previously from Z3 website. When I build the test_capi example, which comes along with the source code, I get the union of the error messages above.

What is the nature of the problem? Are there any prerequisites for the system for using Z3?

On another Debian 6.0 machine everything goes smoothly. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using the official src release or master branch. If that is the case, could you try to compile `test_capi` using in the `test_capi` directory?

```
gcc -o test_capi -I ../lib test_capi.c -L ../bin/external -lz3 -lstdc++ -lgomp
```

In the command above we are explicitly telling `gcc` to link with the C++ standard and OMP libraries.
For the c++ example, you just need to include `-lgomp`, since g++ will link with the C++ standard library by default. You can find other missing dependencies using `ldd`:

```
ldd ../bin/external/libz3.o
```

That being said, I'm working on a new build system for Z3, you can try it by getting the `unstable` branch from codeplex. Could you give a try? It would be great to have your feedback to make the build to go smoothly in many more platforms.

Comment: Thanks, the flags -lstdc++ -lgomp worked for me! Another workaround discovered was to exclude /usr/lib from LD_LIBRARY_PATH - it seems that different version of libstdc++ was used at runtime than that provided by GCC 4.4.3, since that machine has also older GCC version installed.

Comment: As for the unstable branch, build was not successful. Python used on Lenny is 2.5 (see http://wiki.debian.org/Python), and it seems that newer version is needed:
    [...]
    Generated 'src/api/dotnet/Enumerations.cs'[...]
    File "scripts/update_api.py", line 663
    except Exception as ex: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Thanks for trying the unstable branch. I will try to support Python 2.5.